# Can I define a TypeScript type as all possible resulting values from typeof?

Tags: typescript

I am looking to define a type as all of the possible resulting values from using the `typeof` operator on something.

Essentially, I am looking for a quicker way to do this, without any sort of intermediate function or variable.

```
function getTypeOf(value: any) {
  return typeof value;
}

type T0 = ReturnType<typeof getTypeOf>; // "string" | "number" | "bigint" | "boolean" | "symbol" | "undefined" | "object" | "function"
```

How can I get TypeScript to generate the same `T0` type (`"string" | "number" | "bigint" | "boolean" | "symbol" | "undefined" | "object" | "function"`) without an intermediate function or variable whose existence is only to help generate this type?

Note: this does not have much practical application at the moment, I'm just curious if this is possible.

Comment: Remember, TypeScript is just a way of annotating JavaScript to help with type safety. It doesn't add any additional functionality, and it doesn't exist at runtime. So you can't return a type from a function, like in your example code there.

Comment: @MarkHanna 'typeof value' will return a string (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof). The code above works and achieves the desired results, but I was wondering if TypeScript had a nicer way of doing this that doesn't require an intermediate.

Comment: Ah of course! Sorry, you're right of course. Bit of a short circuit on my part, thinking of the TypeScript context made my think only of the [typeof](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/typeof-types.html) type operator rather than the native JavaScript one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works and is a bit shorter than yours:

```
const uselessVariable = typeof (1 as any);

// type Test = "string" | "number" | "bigint" | "boolean" | "symbol" | "undefined" | "object" | "function"
type Test = typeof uselessVariable;
```

Unfortunately it seems there is no way to do this without creating a useless intermediate variable; something like `type Test = typeof typeof (1 as any)` would be simpler but [it's not allowed](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/typeof-types.html):

> TypeScript intentionally limits the sorts of expressions you can use `typeof` on.
>
> Specifically, it’s only legal to use `typeof` on identifiers (i.e. variable names) or their properties.

So it's a syntax error to use `typeof` in a type context unless it's followed by an identifier. That means it really is necessary to declare an identifier (in Javascript-land) in order to construct the type you want programmatically.

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBArhApgG0RCA1AhgJwJZYBGqMAvDFAJ4AOiIAZjABQCMMWE7YlAlANwBYAFDCA9KIo1EMACppY5AETR8YAOaKYAHxiKwcALaFEOTTsWE8avGChndhECFRYw95ZSPP3cMABNEehtEP3cQQgArRGA7bV16Xxi8cEVhKlpZeTJJWgZ4JFR0bHwiVEEhIA)