# Programatic way to get list of JS primitive types

Tags: javascript, typescript

Does JS expose a list of primitive types that can be accessed programmatically, or is there a built in method to find out if a string is a type? This is a somewhat contrived language-based question and *not* intended to solve a specific algorithm.

Besides manually hard-coding array of `['string', 'number', 'boolean', etc...]`, is there a way to programmatically get that list?

Comment: You could hardcode all possible strings. See [here](https://tsplay.dev/mpng6w)

Comment: I'd suggest this is one of these things where hardcoding the list is probably better. With that said, I'm not sure why such a functionality would be needed. It seems a bit like [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: I can see why this looked like an xy question-- I'll update to clarify. I'm looking for an answer to whether the language provides this as functionality (eg an exposed list), not as a solution for a specific algorithm. I wrote the example function to illustrate what I'm asking for.

Comment: I think you can check primitive object wrapper exists in `window` object. For example: 'boolean' -> capitalize -> window['Boolean'] should exists

Comment: There isn't a huge justification for not hard-coding unless the list/method was readily available as a utility in a stable way. I'm asking from a language knowledge standpoint.

Comment: @MaxSinev Interesting line of thinking. Unfortunately, one wouldn't be able to rule out something like `window['Atomics']`

Comment: @MaxSinev try this strategy with `typeof 42n` and see accurate it is. (hint: it isn't)

Comment: @MaxSinev also, if you mean check any string, then you'd run into other problems like "array" which is *not* a valid result for `typeof`, however, it exists as `window["Array"]`. And there are many other properties on `window` that start with a capital letter. *Most* of them are not types that `typeof` would report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no definitive way to get a list of `typeof` results built into JavaScript itself.

If they are exposed somewhere, that would be through a library or as part of the API of a specific environment.

---

In TypeScript you can define a type that covers all possible primitive types as shown [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69655302):

```typescript
const uselessVariable = typeof (1 as any);

// type Test = "string" | "number" | "bigint" | "boolean" | "symbol" | "undefined" | "object" | "function"
type Test = typeof uselessVariable;
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBArhApgG0RCA1AhgJwJZYBGqMAvDFAJ4AOiIAZjABQCMMWE7YlAlANwBYAFDCqtGABU0scmLqMEKNJlwFiiQUID0WmHoB6AfiA)

In TypeScript the JavaScript `typeof` operator is assigned a return type which is restricted to only the results that are possible for it.